# how List<string> become AutoCompleteStringCollection

Tags: c#, autocomplete, desktop-application

I have list, i want to convert it to autoCompleteStringCollection.. And I don't want use foreach.

```
        _textbox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
        _textbox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        _textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = user.GetNameUsers() as AutoCompleteStringCollection;
```

Note user.GetNameUsers() is list.

Code doesn't work, it become null.

Thank you

Comment: It might be important to note: The reason you are getting null is because the `as` operator trys to coerce your List<string> into an `AutoCompleteStringCollection`, but `as` only succeeds if the runtime types match (it won't try any user defined conversions), and the runtime types of `List<string>` and `AutoCompleteStringCollection` are not the same, so it returns null instead.

Comment: owww i got that, thank you . Make it more understand

Comment: `this.textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(new string[] {"anytext","another one"});`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
_textbox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
_textbox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
var autoComplete = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
autoComplete.AddRange(user.GetNameUsers().ToArray());
_textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoComplete;
```

If you need this often, you can write an extension method:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensionsEx
{
    public static AutoCompleteStringCollection ToAutoCompleteStringCollection(
        this IEnumerable<string> enumerable)
    {
        if(enumerable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerable");
        var autoComplete = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        foreach(var item in enumerable) autoComplete.Add(item);
        return autoComplete;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
_textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = user.GetUsers().ToAutoCompleteStringCollection();
```

Comment: And, wrap it in a utility method if you are looking for a one-liner.

Comment: Make sure you strip out any null values form your query when doing this.  I wasn't doing this and it would crash when setting `AutoCompleteCustomSource` with no error messages or dubugging information.

Answer (score 2):

Having checked the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kek20dbk.aspx) for `AutoCompleteStringCollection`, and specifically the constructor I see there is no constructor which takes a `List`.

Therefore, you have 2 options.

1) Use `AddRange` to add all your list items to a new instance of `AutoCompleteStringCollection`

```
var acsc= new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
acsc.AddRange(user.GetNameUsers().ToArray());
```

2) Inherit a new class, which adds the constructor you need, and call much the same code as above internally.

```
public class MyAutoCompleteStringCollection : AutoCompleteStringCollection
{
  public MyAutoCompleteStringCollection(IEnumerable items)
  {
     this.AddRange(items.ToArray())
  }
}
```

Thus you can use

```
_textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = new MyAutoCompleteStringCollection (user.GetNameUsers());
```

Personally, i'd go with option 1 for now.