# Argument Out Of Range Exception when setting combobox 'Droppeddown' value to false

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a combobox used for searching through a database. The dropdown list will show if what the user is searching has matching items, and if not it will retract. However, when my code changes the DroppedDown value to False I immediately get an "ArgumentOutOfRangeException."

The error also includes "Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'."

I'm not sure what's going on because this is the first time I've experimented with comboboxes and auto-updating them.

```
'Search box - Text Update Event
    Private Sub searchBoxCB_TextUpdate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles searchBoxCB.TextUpdate
        'Begin search when user types

        searchBoxCB.Items.Clear()

        'Check if search has numbers in it
        Dim letters() As Char = searchBoxCB.Text
        Dim noNumbers As Boolean = True

        For Each c As Char In letters

            If (IsNumeric(c)) Then

                noNumbers = False

            End If

        Next

        'Only search if no numbers
        If (noNumbers) Then

            searchDataPerson(searchBoxCB.Text, "Person1")
            searchDataPerson(searchBoxCB.Text, "Person2")

        End If

        searchBoxCB.SelectionStart = searchBoxCB.Text.Length + 1 'Move cursor to end

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default

    End Sub

    'Search PERSON operation
    Private Sub searchDataPerson(input As String, person As String)

        Dim itemAdded As Boolean = False

        myConnection.Open()

        Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM AllEmployeeDirectory WHERE " + person + " Like """ + input + "%""" 'Searches for NAMES beginning with input
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection) '*
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader '*

        'Reads through all data
        While dr.Read

            searchBoxCB.DroppedDown = True
            searchBoxCB.Items.Add(dr(person) + " - " + dr("Desk"))
            itemAdded = True

        End While

        If (Not itemAdded) Then

            searchBoxCB.DroppedDown = False 'ERROR OCCURS HERE

        End If

        myConnection.Close()

    End Sub
```

Comment: I have a good feeling it may be your order of operations. Since you didn't post anything I can't confirm that.

Comment: I have a good feeling about Mr Zaggler's good feeling.

Comment: I have a bad feeling about the fact that you posted your code on an external website, rather than as part of your question. :-(

Comment: I just started using Stackoverflow so I'm not familiar with all the aspects of it yet sorry. I had to quickly get the code up as I'm doing other things. Will try and put it in the question soon.

Comment: There we go, code added to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

I could not get your code to work despite *many* variations of it.

However, I got what I think you intend to work by setting the combobox to use autocomplete with this code:

```
Option Infer On

Public Class Form1

    Public Shared Function ACSC(s1 As String, s2 As String) As AutoCompleteStringCollection
        'TODO: substitute your query for obtaining the data here
        Dim a = {"A", "B", "AB", "CBA", "CB", "BC", "ABC"}

        Dim sc As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        sc.AddRange(a.ToArray())

        Return sc

    End Function

    Private Sub searchBoxCB_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles searchBoxCB.TextChanged
        Dim txt = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox).Text
        searchBoxCB.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        searchBoxCB.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ACSC(txt, "")

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        searchBoxCB.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend

    End Sub

End Class
```

(The `.ToArray()` on `a` is just in case `a` happens to be a LINQ method.)

Credit: [how List become AutoCompleteStringCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4678230/1115360)

Comment: This "works" but I'd much rather have the dropdown menu actually drop down for the user to click an item. The way that I'm doing the function after selecting and item would be much easier if I could just have the user select from the dropdown.

Comment: I changed the complete mode to Suggest instead of append and it does what I want, not sure if I can get the index of the suggestions but I will experiment.

Comment: I agree that it is not as nice as the way you're trying to get it work, but at least it shows a dropdown if there is more than one choice. Even if I wrapped the line `searchBoxCB.DroppedDown = False 'ERROR OCCURS HERE` in a Try..Catch and ignored the exception I still got an error when it got to `searchBoxCB.SelectionStart = searchBoxCB.Text.Length + 1`.

Comment: I tried changing the AutoCompleteSource to ListItems and the style to DropDown and I think it may work. I only implemented test data so I will try with actually searching through the database now.

Answer (score 0):

After some frustrating experimenting I came to the realization of a simple solution to the original code. Instead of doing `searchBoxCB.DroppedDown = False` I changed it to `searchBoxCB.DropDownHeight = 1` which effectively does the same thing. Then I also reset the height back to 65 where the DroppedDown value is set to true. It is working as intended now, can't believe I didn't think of this workaround before.